# ifelse statement to create a variable from multiple columns is not working and i cant figure out why

Tags: r

Okay, so I am trying to create one variable based on three different columns: tu_aftermatthew$FLD_ZONE; tu_aftermatthew$SFHA_TF; tu_aftermatthew$ZONESUBTY, which have the following values (tabulated against each other, the reason for which will become clear below).

```
> with(tu_aftermatthew,table(FLD_ZONE, SFHA_TF, useNA = "always"))
                   SFHA_TF
FLD_ZONE                   F        T     <NA>
  A                        0     2494        0
  AE                       0   286245        0
  AH                       0      621        0
  AO                       0      669        0
  AREA NOT INCLUDED     8257        0        0
  VE                       0     5710        0
  X                 12626557        0        0
  <NA>                     0        0  7241489
> with(tu_aftermatthew,table(ZONE_SUBTY, SFHA_TF, useNA = "always"))
                                                       SFHA_TF
ZONE_SUBTY                                                     F        T     <NA>
  0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD                      159698        0        0
  1 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD CONTAINED IN CHANNEL        0       13        0
  1 PCT CONTAINED IN STRUCTURE, COMMUNITY ENCROACHMENT         8        0        0
  1 PCT CONTAINED IN STRUCTURE, FLOODWAY                       6        0        0
  1 PCT FUTURE CONDITIONS                                   4192        0        0
  1 PCT FUTURE CONDITIONS CONTAINED IN STRUCTURE               1        0        0
  AREA OF MINIMAL FLOOD HAZARD                          12459618        0        0
  AREA WITH REDUCED FLOOD RISK DUE TO LEVEE                 3034        0        0
  COMMUNITY ENCROACHMENT AREA                                  0     1007        0
  FLOODWAY                                                     0    17059        0
  STATE ENCROACHMENT AREA                                      0      294        0
  <NA>                                                      8257   277366  7241489
>
```

I want a FLOOD_RISK column to have "SFHA_INLAND" for all instances where SFHA_TF is T and the FLD_ZONE is not VE. Looking at table one, that should be 29,0029 as SFHA_INLAND total. I want the ones where FLD_ZONE is VE to be SFHA_COASTAL, this should be 5710 total.

Then, I want to take all the ones where the ZONE_SUBTY is "0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD" to be 500_FLOOD. None of these values overlap with SFHA_TF == T, and therefore, none overlap with ZONE_SUBTY == VE (which are all SFHA_TF == T).

The end result should be:

```
> table(tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK) 

  500_FLOOD SFHA_INLAND   SFHA_COASTAL  
     159698      90029           5710
```

However, when I use ifelse statements to try to make this work, it doesn't.

```
> tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(tu_aftermatthew$SFHA_TF == "T", "SFHA_INLAND", NA)
> tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(tu_aftermatthew$FLD_ZONE  == "VE", "SFHA_COASTAL", tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK)
> tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(tu_aftermatthew$ZONE_SUBTY  == "0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD", "500_FLOOD", tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK)
> 
> table(tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK, useNA = "always" ) 

  500_FLOOD SFHA_INLAND        <NA> 
     159698       18373    19993971
```

I split it up into FLOOD_RISK and FLOOD_RISK1, and you can see what's happening between the second ifelse statement and the third; and it seems that the third ifelse statement is canabalizing the SFHA_INLAND and SFHA_COASTAL, and it really shouldn't, because the ~.2pct doesn't overlap with the SFHA at all.

```
tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(tu_aftermatthew$SFHA_TF == "T", "SFHA_INLAND", NA)
tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(tu_aftermatthew$FLD_ZONE  == "VE", "SFHA_COASTAL", tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK)
tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK1 <- ifelse(tu_aftermatthew$ZONE_SUBTY  == "0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD", "500_FLOOD", tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK)
    > table(tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK, useNA = "always" )
    SFHA_COASTAL  SFHA_INLAND         <NA> 
            5710       290029     19876303 
    > table(tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK1, useNA = "always" )
    
      500_FLOOD SFHA_INLAND        <NA> 
         159698       18373    19993971
```

I tried making test data, as shown below, but it seemed to work, so I am a bit stuck.

```
FLD<-c("A","A","V","X","X")
SFHA<-c("T","T","T","F","F")
DESC<-c("1","1","1","0", ".2")
df<-data.frame(FLD, SFHA, DESC)
df

df$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(df$SFHA == "T", "SFHA_INLAND", NA)
df$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(df$FLD  == "V", "SFHA_COASTAL", df$FLOOD_RISK)
df$FLOOD_RISK <- ifelse(df$DESC  == ".2", "500_FLOOD", df$FLOOD_RISK)
df

  FLD SFHA DESC   FLOOD_RISK
1   A    T    1  SFHA_INLAND
2   A    T    1  SFHA_INLAND
3   V    T    1 SFHA_COASTAL
4   X    F    0         <NA>
5   X    F   .2    500_FLOOD
```

Comment: If your test data works but your real data doesn't, try slowly simplifying your real data until you get something that works.  You can probably find the problem this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why what you're doing isn't working, but here's a way to do this more efficiently to try:

```
tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK <- NA_character_
tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK[tu_aftermatthew$SFHA_TF == "T"] <- "SFHA_INLAND"
tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK[tu_aftermatthew$FLD_ZONE  == "VE"] <- "SFHA_COASTAL"
tu_aftermatthew$FLOOD_RISK[tu_aftermatthew$ZONE_SUBTY  == "0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD"] <- "500_FLOOD"
```

Comment: I don't know why this works and the less efficient way doesn't, but this does work and right now that's just all the amazingness I need in the world. Thank you!